# How to read a "C source, ISO-8859 text"

Tags: python, unicode

I have this [myfile](http://pastebin.com/TqwHnutg) (which I have pasted, I hope the relevant data with the problems has survived the copy/pasting). I try to read that file with:

```
import codecs
codecs.open('myfile', 'r', 'utf-8').read()
```

But this gives:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 7128: invalid continuation byte
```

If I check the file:

```
» file myfile
myfile: C source, ISO-8859 text
```

- How can I read that kind of file (ISO-8859) in python?
- In the general case, how can I know how a file is encoded?

Lots of times I am dealing with files which have not been generated by me (system files, random files downloaded from the internet, random files contributed by providers, customers, ...): those files do not provide a clue of the encoding they are using. Being in a multi-cultural environment (Europe), it is difficult to know how those files have been encoded. Most of the times, even the person providing the files has no clue about encoding, which can be happening behind the scenes by the editor/tool of choice. How to be sure about the encoding being used, on a file-by-file basis?

Comment: The file you put on pastebin.com did not retain the bytes you had trouble with.

Comment: Strange: visual inspection tells me they are there (line 151)

Comment: Ah, indeed, but the data is UTF8 encoded, so the Latin-1 encoding I opened the file with didn't mind, nor did UTF8 fail. :-) Your browser must've adjusted the encoding after using it's own guesser.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You change the codec in the `open()` command; the ISO-8859 standard has multiple codecs, I picked Latin-1 for you here, but you may need to pick another one:

```
codecs.open('myfile', 'r', 'iso-8859-1').read()
```

See the [`codecs` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html) for a list of valid codecs. Judging by the pastie data, iso-8859-1 is the correct codec to use, as it is suited for Scandinavian text.

Generally, without other sources, you cannot know what codec a file uses. At best, you can guess (which is what `file` does).

Comment: Thanks. This is really unfortunate. Is this a design flaw of unicode? I mean, having a file encoded, but having no way of telling what encoding the file uses strikes me as a severe shortcoming. When my tool runs in production I won't be there to change manually the codec. Must I keep a *separate* mapping of `file:encoding`? Should I *always* try a list of possible codecs? Can I have false positives?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Unicode; it is a flaw of the file format to not include the codec used. If you were to try all codecs, you *will* run into false positives, yes, more likely so than hitting a the right codec in fact. You could use [`chardet`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) to try to make a more educated guess.

Comment: Mmmm. Right. A flaw of the file format *when* using unicode. Opening a non-unicode file *never* causes trouble. Which is what (wrongly?) gives me the feeling that unicode is the culprit. I think it has been an error to start distributing unicode-encoded files without embedded information about the codec used.

Comment: Unicode is a standard, not an encoding. There are such thing as a non-unicode file; most text you don't have trouble with is ASCII encoded; but for the wider world that is simply not expressive enough. You may want to read up on what Unicode *means*: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: Source code files are just plain text files, a format that stems from times when computers weren't as connected as they are today and interoperability was not a concern.

Comment: I see. So the process has been: "we have been using ASCII encoded files (a unicode subset? - before unicode even existed - funny) for 30+ years, and everything worked fine. Now we come up with other encodings (latin-1, whatever), and we do not provide any way to our tools to guess if the files that we distribute are still using the old ascii encoding or if they are using one of the new encoding pages". That strikes me as a very bad process. How difficult would have been to make sure that the files have this information embedded? How much trouble would this spare?

Comment: No, not everything worked fine. But mostly, we got by. Mostly, computing took place in a limited world where you picked the codec once and didn't have to deal with a mix of files.

Comment: And old habits die hard, new formats have been introduced but never managed to displace simple text files, etc.

Comment: And thanks for the link - I have already read that in the past. But, that is a lot of prose to say "we really messed-up this one, so now you have to read (and re-read) lots of documentation to be able to do simple things (like read a file) that your tools should be able to do for you - but can't because we do not include that information in the encoded files, sorry"

Answer (score 34):

With python 3.3 you can use the built in open function

```
open("myfile",encoding="ISO-8859-1")
```

Comment: It took me 15 minutes of Googling to find this simple solution. Thanks!